# C++: Output file of system command not generated

Tags: c++, cmd, grep

I am trying to run a shell command from my code. However, the output file (ts.dat) is not generated. 
Can somebody let me know how to solve this problem?

```
string cmd1, input;
cout << "Enter the input file name: ";
cin >> input;

cmd1 = "grep 'DYNA>' input | cut -c9-14 > ts.dat";
system((cmd1).c_str());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cmd1="grep 'DYNA>' "+input+" | cut -c9-14 > ts.dat";
```

Placing `input` inside the quotes will let the compiler parse it as a string instead of a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Edit this line:

```
cmd1="grep 'DYNA>' input | cut -c9-14 > ts.dat";
```

To this:

```
cmd1="grep 'DYNA>' " + input + " | cut -c9-14 > ts.dat";
```

You need to actually use the value from the `input` string.  The way you have your code currently, you are just writing the word `input` in your string and not using the value that is stored in the string.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I could see that my command line is executed by taking the current input file. However the output ts.dat is still not generated. I used the same command in the terminal to generate the output and it works. But through the system(cmd), it does not work. :(

Comment: I am trying to execute multiple commands from a single system(cmd) statement and probably that has caused this problem of output not getting generated.

Comment: @vidhya - Make sure that you are looking in the correct spot for ts.dat.  It should be in the working directory of your program.

Comment: system (cmd1;cmd2) or system (cmd1 && cmd2) does not work. So when I gave individual commands like system(cmd1); and system(cmd2); it worked. Thanks guys....

Comment: Could you please let me know how to add integer to command. My command line is cmd="catdcd -o f.xyz -otype xyz -first "+ff+" -last "+lf+"";